# Why does my div disappears?

Tags: css, html, web

In css when i give my div height a percentage value the div completely disappears, heres what im doing

```
<html>
...
...
<div id="logcontainer">
  <div><div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

this is not the actual html but it sums up what im trying to do, heres my CSS

```
  #logcontainer {
   width:100%;
   min-height:100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   background-color: #7f7f7f;

   }
```

whenever the height has a percentage value the div disappears, the width works but no height?, when I use ems or rem it works perfectly, any ideas?

Comment: seting a percentage size on an element makes that element's size relative to the containing parent's size. what's #logcontainer contained in, other than the html/body tags?

Comment: 100% height won't work unless the parent has a defined height. Does yours?

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is `html, body { height: 100% }`, if i'm understanding your question correct

Answer (score 1):

Set height of body 100%, then it will work. Since you need to set a 100% height on your parent element, in this case your body. The div tag is a container, but it is contained in the body tag... the body tag, unfortunately is not treated the same on all browsers... in some it is sized to fit the browser's available space... in some browsers the body tag is sized to fit the minimum height required to fit the current contents.... So a div tag set to 100% would size differently on each...in fact if empty, the div tag might not even show up on some browsers, since an empty body would be, potentially, 0px high...

```
     html, body 
       {
          height: 100%; 
         width: 100%;  
         margin: 0;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution :

```
html, body {    height: 100%;    }
```

but it just a solution you need to understand why is happened , this happened because your element is a block level element which wrap up your whole content width and height width  as a 100%
but this is not the case with height you need to specify the related to content to give a height in percentages like as above body has given 100%

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/RRktN/)